# Symfony 3, валидация полей формы

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Здравствуйте!
У меня такой вопрос:  мне нужно сделать валидацию полей в форме. И вывод ошибок в форме
Например одно из полей сейчас в Entity:

```
/**
 * @var string $email
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;
```

потом формирую форму

```
 ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('error_bubbling' => true,))
```

Затем вывожу

```
<div class="cart_row "><label for="email">E-mail</label>

            {{ form_widget(form_user.email) }}
            <p>{{ form_errors(form_user.email) }}</p>

        </div>
```

Собственно тут {{ form_errors(form_user.email) }} я хочу вывести ошибку, но почему-то она не выводится.

В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Параметр `error_bubbling` же вроде вроде передает ошибки к "parent" полю или форме, может поэтому не отображает ошибку т.к. она привязана не к конкретному полю "email" а к самой форме (это просто догадка, не проверял сейчас этого).